# Ruby on Rails: stripping file extension from image request and redirecting to 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

An image is located in the Rails directory at `public/images/subDir/X.png`.

In the development environment, this loads perfectly.

In production, Rails strips off the file extension (.png) and redirects requests to `public/images/subDir/X` instead, which results in a 404.

How do you get Rails to not redirect image requests like this?

We're using RoR 3.2.x.

Routes file below.

```
Test::Application.routes.draw do


    ###########################################################################
    # Designs
    ###########################################################################
    match '/design' => 'default#design'


    # The priority is based upon order of creation:
    # first created -> highest priority.
    root :to => 'default#home'

    # Sample of regular route:
    #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
    # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'

    # Catches all unknown requests
    match '*url' => 'default#error_404'


    # Sample of named route:
    #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
    # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

    # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
    #   resources :products

    # Sample resource route with options:
    #   resources :products do
    #     member do
    #       get 'short'
    #       post 'toggle'
    #     end
    #
    #     collection do
    #       get 'sold'
    #     end
    #   end

    # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
    #   resources :products do
    #     resources :comments, :sales
    #     resource :seller
    #   end

    # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
    #   resources :products do
    #     resources :comments
    #     resources :sales do
    #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
    #     end
    #   end

    # Sample resource route within a namespace:
    #   namespace :admin do
    #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
    #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
    #     resources :products
    #   end

    # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
    # just remember to delete public/index.html.
    # root :to => "welcome#index"

    # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

    # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
    # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
    # match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

Comment: What does your routes.rb look like?

Comment: Is the redirection done by Rails or your app server like nginx?

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran updated the question with the routes file. Is this how you determine who does the redirection?

Comment: @KyleDecot updated the question. thanks!

Comment: what is `config.serve_static_files` in production.rb?

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran it's set to false. Setting it to true didn't help, though. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try removing `match '*url' => 'default#error_404'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a spelling mistake in the image name, though it's unclear why the file extension was getting stripped.